# How to load a filestream image

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a filestream of a image and I want to load this into a `Image` element.but my element show a white screen:

my image:

https://ccg24.com/w/kasian/GetListSlider/745869/Merchent/Fa/image/512M51

```
<Image elevation={5} resizeMode='stretch' style={{ borderRadius: 16, position: 'absolute',right:4, bottom: 10, alignSelf: 'center', width: (height / 2)+20, height: (height / 2)+10 }} source={{ uri: 'https://ccg24.com/w/kasian/GetListSlider/745869/Merchent/Fa/image/512M512' }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Image` component. It works. But `elevation` is not the property of the `Image` component. Maybe your network is slow so that it shows a white screen.

And Please pay attention to the [position](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/layout-props#position). Absolute positioning is always just relative to the parent.

```
<Image style={{ borderRadius: 16, right:4, bottom: 10, alignSelf: 'center', width: (400 / 2)+20, height: (400 / 2)+10 }} source={{ uri: 'https://ccg24.com/w/kasian/GetListSlider/745869/Merchent/Fa/image/512M512' }} />
```